# exit() with message and non-zero exit status

Tags: php

I have two files:
first.php:

```php
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
 exit("Unable"); //1
 #exit(1);  //2
 #exit(); //or exit(0) //3
?>
```

second.php:

```php
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
 exec("./first.php",$out,$err);
 var_dump($out);
 echo "\n".$err;
?>
```

Now, When I run second.php with line #1 in first.php I have "Unable" in $out and 0 in $err. but with two other exits I have that digit in $err. 
How can I have non-zero in $err when I execute exit with string message?
I have tested 2>&1 but it's useless.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
exit("hi");
```

Is the same as:

```
echo "hi";
exit(0);
```

So just echo the statement :)

```
echo "Unable";
exit(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a string exit code.  Exit codes are integers only.

Comment: Should I define a personal_exit function and at first print error and after that exit with non-zero status? Is this only way?

Answer (score 0):

You can exit with a string message and that will print it on the standard output, but as for the exit code, that's an integer, and the string will be transformed into a 0 which is a successful exit code.

Answer (score 0):

You can even call a function when exiting.

```
  function execute() { echo "whatever"; }
  exit(execute());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `die("Unable");`

Comment: Does `die` exit with `1` if you give it a string parameter?

Comment: No, die print string argument and exits with statuscode 0. But if you pass a integer it will use it for statuscode